# Variables globales entre funciones en Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, funciones, variables-globales

Muy buenas, estoy intentando acceder a la misma variable desde todos los scope (en el módulo y en las funciones)

```
global x

def func1():
    global x
    x = "Hola mundo"

def func2():
    print(x)

func2()
```

El problema es que da error al intentar imprimir x en la "func2()".

La pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo acceder desde func2() a la misma variable "x" de func1()?

Gracias de antemano, la verdad es que con una función sale fácil, pero con dos o más, me es imposible.

Comment: Si le doy un  valor a x desde fuera de las funciones va bien.

Comment: Pero yo quiero manejar el x = "Hola mundo" fuera de la propia función.

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo error: NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Al usar la palabra reservada `global`, avisas al intérprete de que esa variable pertenece al ámbito global.

Por lo tanto, su uso fuera de ninguna función es inocuo: declara que una variable pertenece al ámbito global, cuando ya estás en él.

Dentro del cuerpo de una función, le indicas al intérprete que dicha variable pertenece a otro ámbito. **Pero** ... no la declaras ni asignas ningún valor, solo das el aviso al intérprete de que dicha variable pertenece al ámbito global.

Por tanto, antes de poder leer su valor, **sigues teniendo que asignarle uno primero**:

```
def func1():
    global x
    x = "Hola mundo"

def func2():
    global x
    print(x)

func1()
func2()
```